Why does it make sense to say that "full shells" have 0 angular momentum even when not using the configuration model?
When talking about the periodic table, one is often confronted with the notion of a 'configuration of electrons', i.e. we have the configuration $1s^22s^22p^2$ for carbon for example. This notion stems from the Thomas-Fermi approximation, where we find an effective potential in which the electrons are and do not interact with each other. Thus, we have a quasi-noninteracting Fermi gas and can simply fill the states from lowest energy to the highest energy. The Thomas-Fermi model uses the Hartree approximation and thus does not take into account exchange effects (antisymmetrization of the multi-electron state) and correlation effects (in general, we need a linear combination of Slater determinants).
When taking into account the whole interaction of the electrons among each other (but no LS-coupling yet), we get the Hamiltonian
$$\hat{H} = \sum_{i=1}^N (\frac{\hat{p}_i^2}{2m}-\frac{Ze^2}{\hat{r}_i}) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{e^2}{|\hat{\mathbf{r}}_i - \hat{\mathbf{r}}_j|}$$
This Hamiltonian obviously breaks the symmetry under rotation for single electrons, thus we need to go to a basis with 'good' quantum numbers: The $LS$-multiplets.
I want to illustrate my question with the example of carbon. In order to find the 'possible multiplets with this configuration', we assume that the full shells have $0$ angular momentum and spin and build possible multiplets with the remaining two p electrons, giving us the three possibilities ($L=0, S=0; L=2, S=0; L=1, S=1$) so that the full wave function is antisymmetric (how fortunate that we do not have to use Young Tableaux for two electrons!).
But why can we assume in the first place that closed shells have $0$ angular momentum? The concept of a closed shell has no meaning when we take the full Hamiltonian into account. My problem is the seemingly random mixing of a rough first approximation with the exact numerical solution to the full problem. Why is it consistent to do that? As far as I know, for light elements, we solve this problem numerically accurate and then treat the $LS$-coupling as a perturbation to find the fine structure. It would make sense if the interaction term was also treated as such, then we could go back to the non-interacting basis and use it here, but that is not the case for the multiplets.
Edit: My suspicion is that the effective-potential model approximates the behavior of the multiparticle-wave function sufficiently good when shells are full, and there it yields that the total angular momentum is $0$ in the ground state. Therefore, the problem reduced to a 2-electron-problem in the case of carbon. We would thus be mixing together the approximations where they are accurate enough. Is this true?

I am not sure what it is you are asking about. Although Hartree-Fock is an uncorrelated approximation to the underlying correlated system, its simplicity and overall goodness makes it such that we are rather mired in its concepts when we discuss any system. That is, I cannot be sure that you are actually discussing something outside of that framework. However, "closed subshells contribute nothing to angular momentum" is a generally true statement that you ought to prove; as long as closed subshells are a good approximation, you can prove that any choice of basis will still end up zeroing.

This was going to be a comment, not an answer, because I am guessing that you are happy with L and S quantum numbers for atomic hydrogen and so are happy that for n=2 there are 8 possible combinations of
L=0 ml=0, S=1/2 ms=+1/2, L=0 ml=0, S=1/2 ms=-1/2;
L=1 ml=+1, S=1/2 ms=+1/2; L=1 ml=+1, S=1/2 ms=-1/2;
L=1 ml=0, S=1/2 ms=+1/2; L=1 ml=0, S=1/2 ms=-1/2;
L=1 ml=-1, S=1/2 ms=+1/2;  L=1 ml=-1, S=1/2 ms=-1/2;
and I am guessing you know that the simplistic explanation is that the 8 'states' of the electron in n=2 for C  have these same angular momenta ml, ms values even though C is a multielectron atom...... so put 8 electrons in the C n=2 or lets say Ne n=2 (which is really full with 8) and sum of all the ml and ms is equal to zero - and this also works for $s^2$ and $p^6$ full 'subshells'
And so I think the simple answer may be just that when you use multielectron atom theory you get the same angular momenta as you get for the single electron case of H...
... but I think you probably know this, but this 'comment' is now too long for a comment, so has to be an answer.
I remember hearing in a talk that for the shape/order/degerenacies of $\pi$ orbitals of C$_{60}$ molecules you get the same answer by calculation for simple Huckel theory as you get with more complicated theories. Better theories, of course, give better energies, closer to reality.
Another point of view is to think about a lump of bulk metal that really will have a fermi gas of electrons - there is a net zero current as the electrons fill states that 'balance' each other other - unless an electric field is applied and then the population shifts a bit to allow a current to flow. -- in the same way you fill up a subshell and the is no residual angular momentum.
Hope this is some help
